# CSS conflict with :after and .truncate

Tags: lightning-aura-components, css

I have a Lightning component where I'm setting up a custom object record that is linked to a Contact, as well as the option to relate it to opportunities and cases. As the user selects the Contact, Case/Opportunity, it displays like this:

[image: Tree View]

Here's the markup, using `<ul>` for the Contact, and `<li>` for the Case and/or Opportunity.

```
<div class="tree">
        <aura:if isTrue="{! !v.NeedRecipient}">
            <ul>
                <lightning:icon iconName="{!v.ToIcon}" size="small"/>
                <span>&nbsp;{!v.To}</span>
            </ul>
        </aura:if>

        <aura:if isTrue="{! v.Case != null}">
            <li>
                <lightning:icon iconName="standard:case" size="small"/>
                &nbsp;&nbsp;{!v.Case.Subject}
            </li>
        </aura:if>

        <aura:if isTrue="{! v.Opportunity != null}">
            <li>
                <lightning:icon iconName="standard:opportunity" size="small"/>
                &nbsp;&nbsp;{!v.Opportunity.Name}
            </li>
        </aura:if>
    </div>
```

And the CSS:

```
.THIS .truncate {
    width:90%;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
  }


.THIS.tree{
    margin:0 auto;
    width: 100%;
}

.THIS.tree ul{
    padding: 5px 5px 0 5px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}


.THIS.tree li{
    margin-left: 28px;
    list-style-type: none;
    position: relative;
    padding: 5px 5px 0 5px;
}

.THIS.tree li::after{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
    height: 32px;
    width: 16px;
    right: auto;
    left: -11px;
    top: -14px;
}
```

My issue is that the Case subject or the Opportunity Name needs to be truncated so that it doesn't wrap. I have a .truncate CSS class, but when I add that into the markup, it corrupts the tree structure.

Here I've added truncate to the case `<li>`, but not the opportunity `<li>`:

```
        <aura:if isTrue="{! v.Case != null}">
            <li class="truncate">
                <lightning:icon iconName="standard:case" size="small"/>
                &nbsp;&nbsp;{!v.Case.Subject}
            </li>
        </aura:if>
```

With this result: the line descending from the icon above, and part of the horizontal line connecting the case icon disappear.

[image: Corrupted Tree View]

Any ideas?